# Python : a way to calculate

Tags: python

Is there any way to calculate the counting of names in the list?

The following example is written by using the method of count().

Then, the outcome should be the dictionary as the same output.

> Attention: do not use built-in count() method and should return a 
>        dictionary. If the list is empty, it will return an empty          dictionary.

```
a=['Mary', 'David','Grace','Curtis','Alice','Joe','Grace']

# use count
print(dict(map(lambda x  : (x , list(a).count(x)) , a)))
```

> output: {'Mary': 1, 'David': 1, 'Grace': 2, 'Curtis': 1, 'Alice': 1,
>   'Joe': 1}

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/365102

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq the way you introduce is also using count method. The answer should not use pandas or count.

Comment: Oh. It's pretty simple to roll your own, no? Just loop over all items. Increment counts depending on the item. https://repl.it/@SicariusNoctis/BreakableAromaticClosedsource

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq you used built-in count method.

Comment: What is a built in count method and how did I use it?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq ok, you did not use count method. but your answer is defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Mary': 1, 'David': 1, 'Grace': 2, 'Curtis': 1, 'Alice': 1, 'Joe': 1}).  return so many unneccessary words.

Comment: `print(dict(counts))`. Alternatively, you can get by without using `defaultdict` at all, but it's the recommended style.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
c = dict(Counter(long_list_with_duplicates))
print(c)
```

Comment: if do not use counter. The example already uses counter.

Comment: @AAlex your example uses `count()`, not `Counter()`.

Comment: not use build-in count() method

Comment: But it doesn't do that. It is using the class Counter, from the collections module instead of the built in count method for lists

Comment: The outcome should be a dictionary. That will not be a dictionary.

Comment: I've edited the answer now by wrapping the counter in a dict()

Comment: @AAlex Use a `defaultdict`. `from collections import defaultdict counts = defaultdict(int) for name in a: counts[name] += 1 print(dict(counts))`

Comment: if the list is empty, it should return an empty dictionary.

Comment: using counter instead of built-in count() -->strange.(but cannot tell how is strange.)